# Flattening columns in sub associations with sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have three different tables that hold data for a group of users, the presence for the users in those groups, and the actual user data. When pulling just the members data I am able to flatten it all without nesting with

```
GroupUsers.findAll({
    raw: true,
    attributes: [
        'userID',
        'userRole',
        [Sequelize.col('User.username'), 'username'],
    ],
    where: {
        groupID: 'some group id'
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: User,
            attributes: []
        }
    ],
})
```

Which will return

```
{
    userID: "1234",
    status: "user",
    username: "foo",
}
```

However, if I try to do the same with a subassociation by doing

```
Groups.findOne({
    where: {
        active: true,
        id: 'some group id'
    },
    include: {
        model: GroupUsers,
        attributes: [
            'userID',
            'userRole',
            [Sequelize.col('User.username'), 'username'],
        ],
        as: "members",
        include: {
            model: User,
            attributes: []
        }
    }
})
```

This no longer works and I get an error that `members.User.username` is an unknown column.

A similar issue can be found when trying to reference the nested data in a where clause with the include such as with

```
include: {
    model: GroupUsers,
    where: {
        '$User.username$': 'foo'
    }
    ...
}
```

Once again stating that this is an unknown column.

Does anyone know if there is a proper way to do this that I am missing or does sequelize just not allow referencing sub associations within another association and only allows this kind of behavior at the top level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved by using **[sequelize literal](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-literal)**, it's a little raw but it works but you must know all associations before the column.
In your case it would be something like this:

```
Groups.findOne({
  where: {
    active: true,
    id: 'some group id'
  },
  include: {
    model: GroupUsers,
    attributes: [
        'userID',
        'userRole',
        [Sequelize.literal('"members->User"."username"'), 'username'],
    ],
    as: "members",
    include: {
        model: User,
        attributes: []
    }
  }
})
```

like this you should avoid sequelize override over that attribute.
to answer your second case when you try to use the where clause, that clause should be inside users

```
include: {
    ...
    include: {
        model: User,
        attributes: [],
        where: {
           username: 'foo'
        },
        required: true
    }
  }
```

instead of this:

```
include: {
   model: GroupUsers,
   where: {
    '$User.username$': 'foo'
   }
   ...
}
```